# Advice with Selenium Project

Tags: java, selenium, testng

This is a Java - Selenium ( any other related technologies ?) project I need to do on the side for a friend, who volunteers at a non-profit organization. I am supposed to create an application to test their web pages. I am more into the server side of java, c, c++. My question is what are the open source technologies and frameworks available which will help me to build a robust test framework, I need to create a process for them, so that any future volunteers with basic knowledge of java and selenium can maintain, add new test cases as and when necessary. I read a little about TestNG but now sure that it is the best out there.

Please suggest best practices for building a java selenium test framework

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)

Comment: JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Selenium 2/WebDriver as the browser automation tool
2. [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/) + [Spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) if you can use Groovy otherwise JUNIT + [PageObject](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) pattern

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a simple homepage without many Javascript, I recommend HTMLUnit since it's faster than Selenium. But you might be interested in Cuke4Duke for BDD style.

https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/tree/master/examples/java-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Junit or TestNG is good choice for using with selenium RC. 1st you should explore ide then go for selenium RC. One good Example is available at http://www.dev2all.com/articles/