# Difference between NG and JUnit framework?? which one is best for testing by using Selenium Web-driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I want to know that what's the difference between NG and Junit and which one is best for automation in Selenium Webdriver. Please explain with example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium-Webdriver Java Framework - TestNG or JUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257435/selenium-webdriver-java-framework-testng-or-junit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation is Testng because, [click here](http://blog.varunin.com/2010/04/what-is-testng-and-whats-difference.html) the Advantages of Testng & Advantages of TestNG over Junit. also [check this](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/)

Comment: This article is from 2010.

Comment: check latest comparison http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/

Comment: @ franz Ebner i am saying Junit & testng both are stronger & i used both but testng is ahead in case of Group test, object parametrization & Dependency tests.

Comment: So think I, but in 2010 the difference was much bigger. JUnit 4 is not that bad though.

Answer (score 0):

On a rough note... TestNG is nothing but Junit along with some extra features like Reports and some annotations. If you are least bothered about the test execution reports, you can go with Junit. If you need html reports you can go with TestNG.

Comment: test reports can be generated using jacoco for JUnit tests as well